# process columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe **df**:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0   a1  NaN  NaN
1   a2   b1  NaN
2   a3   b3   c1
3   a4  NaN   c2
```

I have tried :

`new_df = '[' + df + ']'`

`new_df['Col4']=new_df[new_df.columns[0:]].apply(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis =1)`

`df_final = pd.concat([df, new_df['col4']], axis =1)`

I am getting at this :

[image: wrong dataframe]

I was looking for a robust solution to get to something which must look like this:

[image: expected resultant frame]

I know there is no direct way to do this, the data frame eventually is going to be at least 20k rows and so the question to fellow stack-people.

Thanks.

let me know if you have any more questions and I can edit the question to add points.

Comment: Can you please try and provide your sample data in a structure we can replicate? Thanks

Comment: I did not follow your question - do you want sample data? I think any excel sheet that has text that can be merged should be okay. Here is one example:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiLnKnela3uAhUtwzgGHb4ZCTIQFjABegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2Ffwlink%2F%3FLinkID%3D521962&usg=AOvVaw2vd06xWtIxQTTv-3KBpe8y

Comment: I also think that the example of what you want to obtain is wrong: the last value of `Col4` should be `a4,[c2]` (not `a3,[c2]`), am I right?

Comment: @EnricoGandini: sorry. My bad - I will correct that.. THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
new_col = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    
    val1 = row["Col1"]
    val2 = row["Col2"]
    val3 = row["Col3"]
    
    new_val2 = f",[{val2}]" if pd.notna(val2) else ""
    new_val3 = f",[{val3}]" if pd.notna(val3) else ""
    
    val4 = f"{val1}{new_val2}{new_val3}"
    new_col.append(val4)

df["Col4"] = new_col
```

Maybe my answer is not the most "computationally efficient", but if your dataset is 20k rows, it will be fast enough!
I think my answer is very easy to read, and it is also easy to adapt it to different scenarios!

Comment: Answer not testing misisng values, I  got wrong output.

Comment: @jezrael
You are right, I edited my answer.
My previous answer worked perfectly in a DataFrame where missing values were of `None` type. But then you included the code-block in your answer, and missing values are of `np.nan` type.
And `bool(None) == False`, whereas `bool(np.nan) == True`.
Now it should work, please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

You can add `[]` for all columns without first not missing value tested with helper `i` from `enumerate`:

```
def f(x):
    gen = (y for y in x if pd.notna(y))
    return ','.join(y if i == 0 else '['+y+']' for i, y in enumerate(gen))

#f = lambda x: ','.join(y if i == 0 else '['+y+']' for i, y in enumerate(x.dropna()))
df['col4'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)

  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4          col4
0   a1  NaN   d8  NaN       a1,[d8]
1   a2   b1   d3  NaN  a2,[b1],[d3]
2  NaN   b3   c1  NaN       b3,[c1]
3   a4  NaN   c2  NaN       a4,[c2]
4  NaN  NaN   c6   d5       c6,[d5]
```

Performance test:

```
#test for 25k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 5000, ignore_index=True)

f1 = lambda x: ','.join(y if i == 0 else '['+y+']' for i, y in enumerate(x.dropna()))
%timeit df.apply(f1, axis=1)
3.62 s ± 21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.apply(f, axis =1)
475 ms ± 3.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: This is working only when col1 is not NaN. 
When col 1 is nan then the expected output is expected to be b4, [c3] but it id [b4] [c3]. 

I think there needs to be another tweak.

Comment: @Vyas - You are right, answer was edited.

Comment: I used 

df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.NsN, regex = True) 

to replace all the empty cells in the df with nan and then it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Vyas - Super! Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your usecase is, but here you go

```
df['Col4'] = df.apply(lambda row:", ".join([(val if val[0]=='a' else "["+val+"]") for val in row if not pd.isna(val)]), axis=1)
```

It joins the rows together, by concatenating their values with `", ".join`, but only if they are not `pd.isna`. It further puts everything in brackets that does not begin with `a`.

Whatever you want to do with it, there probably is a better solution though

Comment: I am looking to concatenate col1, col2 and col3 to get col4 where the first column does not have a bracket and the resultant columns does not contain any nan's. 

Does that help?

Comment: I mean, I see what you want to do (and the snippet does that). I just couldn't imagine what you needed that for